# change sheet name in excel function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to change the sheet name in the function e.g.(='sheet1'Q13) to ('sheet2'Q13) how do I automate for the changes of the sheet name and keep the position of the column e.g.Q13 at the same time?

I couldn't paste out the unevaluated formula so I was not able to use the =REPLACE() functions

Comment: `ctrl+H` old text `'Sheet1'` new text `'Sheet2'`

Comment: Perhaps you could try this `=INDIRECT("'Sheet"&ROW(A1)&"'!Q13")` when filled down it becomes **`Sheet2`** from **`Sheet1`**

Comment: Are you familiar with using `$` to make the cell references absolute? If you use `$Q13`, that will make it so that no matter which row or cell you copy that formula to, it will always stay in column `Q`.

Other than that, P.b's solution should be your fix.

Comment: @RGilchrist within `INDIRECT()` Function the cell reference will not change.

Comment: The $Q13 doesn't work for horizontal increment, which it will remain as $Q13 in the next column, not $Q14 as expected

Comment: @kaihong but you said want to keep the position of Q13 same, have you tried using this one as suggested, wanted to know so I can improvise more `=INDIRECT("'Sheet"&ROW(A1)&"'!Q13")`